# Changing a monthly recurring subscription to yearly recurring subscription for shopify app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

We are running a Shopify app. On our dashboard, we are showing a plans screen from where users can select a specific package. When a user selects a plan, on our backend we have called Shopify API.

> https://{storeUrl}/admin/api/2021-04/recurring_application_charges.json

and passing it data:

```
recurring_application_charge: {
    "name": plan name,
    "price": plan value,
    "return_url": url,
}
```

The problem is, I also want our customers to subscribe to our app recurring yearly. But this Shopify endpoint doesn't take any property like "interval" (which enables us to charge yearly). Asking you guys, maybe you've implemented the same scenario. Thanks.

Comment: You have to utilize the Shopify GraphQL: https://shopify.dev/apps/billing/subscriptions/annual

The REST API doesn't have the ability to set the "interval" property